# How to automatically delete old artifacts in an Apache Archiva

Tags: linux, maven

We have an Apache Archiva server that we use as our main object repository for Maven. This server has been running for years already.

I have noticed that it still stores old version artifacts that are not in use anymore.

That means that I must do come manual cleanup of it to avoid having it consuming too much disk space.

I want to have the artifacts that have not been used in the last X months deleted automatically.

Will be nice to be able to exclude some specific packages from this purge. This will be for locally built packages that are not so easy to rebuild.

I have been looking for a solution for this in Archiva documentation, but I have found nothing. So, I'm considering to use a cron script launching find for that cleanup. But I wonder if there's any other and more elegant solution for this task.